# how to set custom design layout for custom attribute category in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, layered-navigation, magento2.2.7

I have created 3 attributes.
First for Design layout left or right custom category attribute. 
Second for Enable disable custom category attribute.
Third attribute for product which is enable for custom category product.

Now I am looking for solution how to set custom design layout for custom category attribute for custom layered navigation. Else all product will display with default layered navigation.